# Simple sql query to copy fields from another table based on the same key

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking for the simplest query that will allow me to achieve copying some value from table A to table B while they both have a same key to identify what's needed.

I basically have (for example purposes only) 2 tables that represent users.

```
Table A contains USER_NAME, USER_ID, JOINED_DATE, RANK
Table B contains USER_ID, ACCOUNT_DETAILS, ADDRESS, RANK
```

I had a little bug with the RANK one, and i now see that in some cases the RANK is updated only in B, meaning in A its always NULL, but in some case its available at B.
I want to run a DB update that will:

1. check what USERS were created via table A joined last 30 days,
2. and then take that USER_ID and use this Key on table B
3. and check "if this ID in table B has a RANK,
4. copy that RANK to the same USER_ID in table A".

To clarify - All RANK in Table A is empty which is a bug, Some RANK in Table B has data and some is NULL, this is as designed and its OK.  what i want is for both RANK columns to be example the same , in some time period, not generally from the beginning of time.

If you take a look at the example image below, you can see that it copied (based on the condition that its not null and joined date is above 2019:

1. 123 - copied RANK since its valid
2. 111 - copied RANK since its valid
3. 121 - wasn't copied since RANK is empty and date is below 2020
4. 141 - wasn't coped since RANK exists but date is below 2020

[image]

I hope that's understandable, please ask if there are more questions :)

Many thanks in advance good people!

pretty new and haven't touched SQL in quite a while.
this is Oracle SQL if it matters.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added an example image with expected results, tell me if u need more information, also added more details on that example

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing . . . 30 days or in 2020?

Comment: doesnt matter really, i want to run all above 2020, and at some point to run last 30 days, so as long as there's a date check i can play with it, the actual number doesnt matter to me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simple update as follows:

```
Update tablea a
Set a.rank = (select b.rank
From tableb b where b.user_id = a.user_id)
Where exists (select 1 from
Tableb b where b.user_id = a.user_id
And b.rank is not null)
And a.rank is null;
--And a.joined_date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `join`:

```
select a.*, b.rank
from a left join
     b
     on a.user_id = b.user_id and
        a.joined_date >= sysdate - interval '30' day
```

If you want to update the rank in A:

```
update a
    set rank = (select b.rank
                from b
                where a.user_id = b.user_id
               )
    where a.joined_date >= sysdate - interval '30' day;
```

The date comparisons would be slightly different if you want only dates in 2020.